# Uncaught reference error : "function name" not defined error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't figure out why this error keeps occuring in the console though all the syntax seems to be correct. I've also declared the function which the error indicates I didn't. This code is from a tutorial that I am going through online and the code is exactly the same as shown there, but not working.
The code is the following that I did in the snippet in devtools.

```
var output = [];
var count = 1;
function fizzBuzz(){
  output.push(count);
  
  count++;
  console.log(output);
}
fizzBuzz();
```

On calling the function the error as specified in the title shows up.

Comment: Everything seems fine to me... Is this the full code? If not, can you please paste it in?

Comment: Bro I'm blocked to post a pic since it's my first post. But that's the complete code. All I wanted to was call the function as in the last line of the code, but the error keeps showing up.

Comment: I executed your code and it ran fine on my end. Here's a pen demonstrating the same: https://codepen.io/tushar2004/pen/gOPvRvP?editors=1111

Comment: Thank you, bro . It looks right in the pen. Bro now somehow that problem has been gotten rid off but now when I execute it in the chrome dev tool both in the console and in the snippet the result is "undefined". Is there any way I can share pics of this error since I'm not allowed for being a complete beginner here.

Comment: Instead of sharing the image please create a pen as I did and share the link. This way we both would be on the same page and it will be really easy to debug the issue.

Comment: Bro the codes working the same way in my pen too. But the idea here is to keep inserting values beginning from 1 to 100 in the array every time the function is executed, without using any loop. But I'm unable to execute way in codepen , it just displays [1]. I wonder it has to do with any configuration error in the dev tool coz it works just in the tutorial ?

Answer (score -1):

Just use recursion then.

```
var output = [];
var count = 1;
function fizzBuzz(){
  output.push(count);
  
  count++;
  if(count <= 100) {
    fizzBuzz(count);
  }
  console.log(output);
}
fizzBuzz();
```

It will push the count 100 times, each time it's value incremented by 1 without using a loop

Comment: But the task at hand is to do it without recursion. I want to figure out why that code is returning "undefined" in the dev tool console, when it works properly in the tutor's devtool and a number is entered in the array every time the function is run. Without figuring this out I cant proceed furthur ,thats why.